# Output is different in different browsers for this navigation bar, why is it doing this?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm still learning my HTML and CSS, right now I'm practicing navigation bars. This code is displaying different padding for Mozilla and Chrome, why is it doing this? The fact that I can't figure out why is really annoying. I'm going to share the code here.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Practice</title>

        <style>

    /* ====== RESET CODE ======= */  


    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}

    body {
            font-family: arial;
    }

         #top {
                width:100%;
                height:40px;
                background-color:#555;
         }

         .container {
                        margin:0 auto;
                        padding:0px;
                        width: 1000px;

         }

         #nav ul li {
                     float:left;
                     display:block;
                     margin:0px;
         }

         #search-bar {
                    float:right;
                    border: 1px solid;
                    width:315px;
                    position: relative;
                    top:5px;
         }

         .search {
                    width: 100%;
                    padding:2px;
         }

         a {
            padding: 18px 12px;
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
            margin:0px;
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
         }

         a:hover {
             background-color:#777;
             padding:11px 12px;
         }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="top">
            <div class="container">
             <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Jupiter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Venus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Mars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Neptune</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <div id="search-bar">
                    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="search"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All browsers has it's own default css. You try to reset that default css in `RESET CODE`, but I think you are missing some elements. Better try this reset code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
    zoom: 1;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use bootstrap for nav bar:-http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

you can download bootstrap from:http://getbootstrap.com/

it is very easy when you use bootstrap